# Invalid JWT token: JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to access an endpoint and i get the above error in my springboot server, using post i can access the endpoint so the problem i guess is from my front end

Auth service

```
const api = 'http://locahost:8080/api/auth/'

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(api + 'signin', {
      username,
      password
    }, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

UserService

```
const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/test/'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

 
  getAdminContent()  :Observable <any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl + 'patients', {responseType :'text'})
  }
}
```

TokenStorageService

```
const tokenKey  = 'auth-token';
const userKey = 'auth-user';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {

  constructor(private router:Router) { }
  signOut() : void {
    
    window.sessionStorage.clear();

  }
  public saveToken(token:string) :void {
      window.sessionStorage.removeItem(tokenKey);
      window.sessionStorage.setItem(tokenKey, token)
  }
  public getToken() :string | null {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey)
    
  }
  public saveUser( user : any) : void {
 window.sessionStorage.removeItem(userKey)
 window.sessionStorage.setItem(userKey , JSON.stringify(user))
  }
  public getUser(): any {
    const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(userKey);
    if (user) {
      return JSON.parse(user);
    }

    return {};
  }
}
```

AuthInterceptor

```
const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';      


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
 
      authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });

      
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

LoginComponent

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
form : any = {
username : null,
password: null

};
isLoggedIn = false;
isLoginFailed =  false;
errorMessage = '';
roles : string [] =  [ ];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService ,
     private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService , private router: Router, 
      private location: LocationStrategy) {
        history.pushState(null, "null", window.location.href); 
      this.location.onPopState(() => {
        history.pushState(null, "null", window.location.href);
      });
       }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    if (this.tokenStorage.getToken()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
      
    }
  }
  onSubmit(): void {
    const { username, password } = this.form;

    this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);

        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
        this.router.navigate(['/home']).then(()=> window.location.reload());
        
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }
  reloadPage() {
 
    window.location.reload();
  }

}
```

i think the problem is at `const token = this.token.getToken();` which on `consloe.log(token)` returns `undefined` , but still i can't figure out why

I'm trying to GET `http://localhost:8080/api/test/patients` for the user logged in as admin

Checking the request in dev tools i get
[image]

Can somebody help out here please

checking session storage on devtools
[image]
and
[image]

Comment: Your interceptor looks fine. Check if you correctly registered it, and also check if your token service returns the correct token by setting a breakpoint in the interceptor. Also check the request in the developer tools of your browser, to see what's actually sent in the `Authorization` header

Comment: I'm getting "  Authorization: Bearer undefined " when i check the request in dev tools.  Where could i be doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, then your tokenService obviously is not returning a valid token. Did you call `saveToken()` somewhere? If yes, check there if the correct value is written to the session storage ... You can also inspect the session storage in the browser's developer tools

Comment: I'm  still lost bro

Comment: Open the browsers developer tools . If you are using Chrome there is an "Application" tab. Then on the left side you find "Session Storage" expand it and select the correct domain. Then you will see all keys-value pairs. check what the value for `auth-token` is. It probably says `undefined`. So you have called `saveToken` somewhere but passed a parameter of `undefined` to it ...

Comment: I've called `saveToken` on `LoginComponent` where  i've passed a parameter, but i don't see whats wrong . I've edit could you please check

Comment: Well, you are calling `saveToken(data.accessToken)` but the property in you data object is only called `data.token`...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Authorization:Bearer {auth_token}`  to your `httpOptions`

Answer (score 0):

Check the contents of the JWT token you are sending. It is probably malformed as it is missing period separators. A JWT has 3 base64-encoded sections separated by a period as: `HEADER.PAYLOAD.SIGNATURE`.

For example (see also yourself in the "playground" of https://jwt.io/, lines are added by me for readability):

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9
.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ
.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

Comment: how exactly do  i check the contents of the jwt token

Comment: @54V4G3208 you should check what is being sent along with the `Authorization` request header (from Javascript side). In your example is says "undefined"

Comment: I've add some details ,could you please check